# How do I include a file in HTML Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, web-applications

I have attempted to create a new app, with app script, and I am attempting to use scriptlets but without success

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).evaluate().getContent();
}
```

but nothing to do when verifying deployment doesn't work

```
<?!=include('Stylesheet'); ?>
```

please, help me!

Comment: From `TypeError: HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(...).evaluate is not a function (riga 2, file "DoGet")`, I'm worried that my proposed script might not be reflected to your Web Apps. In your situation, it seems that Web Apps is used. So, when you modified the Google Apps Script, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful this.

Comment: You can see the detail of this in the report of "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)". If I misunderstood your current situation, I apologize.

Comment: From `The result is a print of the entire body of the css file on the screen instead of the tag and nothing more`, I could confirm that your issue was resolved. About your new issue, this is different from your question. In this case, your new issue depends on `Stylesheet` of `<?!=include('Stylesheet'); ?>`. But in this case, I cannot see your file of `Stylesheet`. So it is required to know the detail of it. For example, the content of `Stylesheet` is enclosed the style tag like `<style> ... </style>`?

Comment: yes, my Stylesheet file is wrapped in the style tag

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `yes, my Stylesheet file is wrapped in the style tag`, in this case, it is required to know the detail of your current situation. And I would like to support you. But in this case, that is different from this question. So can you post is a new question by including more information? By this, it will help users including me think of the solution. When you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, if `<?!=include('Stylesheet'); ?>` is included in `index.html` file, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).evaluate().getContent();
}
```

#### To:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index').evaluate();
}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}
```

#### Note:

- If `filename` of `include(filename)` has the scriptlets, please modify as follows.

  ```
    function include(filename) {
      return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(filename).evaluate().getContent();
    }
  ```
- In your script, it seems that Web Apps is used. **In this case, when you modified the Google Apps Script, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful this.**
- You can see the detail of this in the report of "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

#### References:

- [createTemplateFromFile(filename)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service#createTemplateFromFile(String))
- [createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service#createhtmloutputfromfilefilename)

Comment: even doing a new deployment I can't get out of the problem, if I add the .evaluate () function this is not recognized

Comment: ok, I understand where i was wrong with respect to your solution however now... I have another problem now it is the css that is printed on the screen and not interpreted ... at least it opens the file this is true but it is not working equally
    function doGet() {
       return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate();
    }
    function include(filename) {
       return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
    }

Comment: @Fabio Mannelli Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About `I have another problem now`, I would like to support you. But unfortunately, I cannot understand your new question. So can you post it as new question by including more information? By this, it will help users including me think of the solution. When you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?